# How to add help to winform c# application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to know that how can I add help support to my winform app.

How do I create chm file for help and how do I integrate it with the application. I want help for almost every control in my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [HelpProvider class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpprovider.aspx).